# How to run local shell script on remote GCP machine via gcloud compute?

Tags: bash, gcloud

I have a script at local machine and want to run it at remote gcp server via gcloud's ssh.

I know how to do that using regular ssh command:

```
ssh user@remotehost "bash -s" < local_script.sh
```

which has been explained at https://askubuntu.com/questions/204065/how-to-run-local-shell-script-on-remote-server-via-ssh

what is I want is to use gcloud computer ssh:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone MYZONE MYINSTANCE --project MYPROJECT ...
```

so far I have tried:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone MYZONE MYINSTANCE --project MYPROJECT -- 'local_script.sh'
```

of course it failed, with error:

```
bash: local_script.sh: command not found
```

How can I do the similar as `ssh user@remotehost "bash -s" < local_script.sh` using gcloud cmd? in the worst case I will copy the file to remote machines and run there but I am not allowed to write anything at the remote machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be invoked in the same way as standalone ssh, you need only include `--` to separate `gcloud` options from arguments given to `ssh`:

```
gcloud compute ssh user@host -- bash -s < local_script.sh
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: Thanks smemsh. it works like charm. initially I did not include "bash -s" at the right place. now I understand, we just need to add all the additional command after -- then gcloud compute will work the same as ssh.